# What does "handelstype" mean?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, terminology

I was looking at the trading information for some stocks listed on the Euronext Paris stock exchange, and I don't understand what "handelstype" means. Some stocks have a "handlestype" of "continuous", while others have a "handelstype" of "double call auction". Here are some screenshots:

[Total SE](https://live.euronext.com/en/product/equities/FR0000120271-XPAR/market-information):

[image: Screenshot]

[Batla Minerals SA](https://live.euronext.com/en/product/equities/FR0010436170-XMLI/market-information):

[image: Screenshot]

What does "handelstype" mean?

Comment: according to google translate it is danish for trade type.

Comment: "handel" means things like commerce, sell, trade, wholesale, contract, etc.  it simply means "trade type," as you'd expect from the examples.  No big deal.

Comment: Could this be a language translation mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per mhoran_psprep and Fattie in the comments, it means Trade Type. I'd like to offer some more evidence that it is (as the asker, Flux, suggested) a translation error.

If you go to the Bonds side of the site (e.g. to
https://live.euronext.com/en/product/bonds/FR0013233384-XPAR/market-information) you'll find that the Trading Type is properly translated. To confirm that's correct, you can change the language for the site in the URL by changing /en to /nl https://live.euronext.com/nl/product/bonds/FR0013233384-XPAR/market-information and you'll find that this block when untranslated uses the name "Handelstype". They must've missed this particular label when translating the analagous HTML block for equities pages.

Also, for what it's worth, the bond HTML block can be generated using the ID of a stock, here is the stock's trading info block: https://live.euronext.com/en/ajax/getFactsheetInfoBlock/STOCK/FR0000120271-XPAR/fs_tradinginfo_block

[image: stock info in stock trading info block (shows handelstype)]

and here is the stock's trading characteristics block (an unused block, which is called for on bond pages):
https://live.euronext.com/en/ajax/getFactsheetInfoBlock/STOCK/FR0000120271-XPAR/fs_tradingcharacteristics_block

[image: stock data in bond trading characteristics block (shows trading type)]